# windows-linux g++ compiler memory error

Tags: linux, windows, memory, g++

I have written my code on Windows VS platform and when I compile it there is no error. But when I try compiling it on linux with g++ compiler I get the error indicated below:

```
[user@ssh ~]$ g++ main.cpp -o main
[user@ssh ~]$ ./main "data1_h1.txt" "data1_r1.txt" 3 "output1_S1"
*** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff795578b4 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x320ec716af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x320ec758db]
./main(__gxx_personality_v0+0x3b2)[0x4013da]
./main[0x401d4b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x320ec1d9c4]
./main(__gxx_personality_v0+0x71)[0x401099]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 18302619                           /users/lnxsrv1/ee/user/main
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 00:16 18302619                           /users/lnxsrv1/ee/user/main
11159000-1117a000 rw-p 11159000 00:00 0 
320e800000-320e81c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1585318                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
320ea1c000-320ea1d000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 1585318                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
320ea1d000-320ea1e000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 1585318                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
320ec00000-320ed4f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1585379                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
320ed4f000-320ef4f000 ---p 0014f000 fd:00 1585379                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
320ef4f000-320ef53000 r--p 0014f000 fd:00 1585379                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
320ef53000-320ef54000 rw-p 00153000 fd:00 1585379                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
320ef54000-320ef59000 rw-p 320ef54000 00:00 0 
320f000000-320f082000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1585438                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
320f082000-320f281000 ---p 00082000 fd:00 1585438                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
320f281000-320f282000 r--p 00081000 fd:00 1585438                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
320f282000-320f283000 rw-p 00082000 fd:00 1585438                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3212800000-321280d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1585420                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
321280d000-3212a0d000 ---p 0000d000 fd:00 1585420                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3212a0d000-3212a0e000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 1585420                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3217000000-32170e6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 782090                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
32170e6000-32172e5000 ---p 000e6000 fd:00 782090                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
32172e5000-32172eb000 r--p 000e5000 fd:00 782090                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
32172eb000-32172ee000 rw-p 000eb000 fd:00 782090                         /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
32172ee000-3217300000 rw-p 32172ee000 00:00 0 
2b43d24f0000-2b43d24f2000 rw-p 2b43d24f0000 00:00 0 
2b43d2508000-2b43d250a000 rw-p 2b43d2508000 00:00 0 
7fff79543000-7fff79558000 rw-p 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fff795fd000-7fff79600000 r-xp 7fff795fd000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

How can I fix that error? Thanks...

Comment: Right now we can just recommend removing the bogous `free()`? We might be able to help better, if you show us the code.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `free` on a memory address that has already been freed, or was never used in the first place. If you compiled the program with debugging information (`-g`) and run the program under the debugger (`gdb`) you might be able to get more information.

Comment: I have shared whole code.

Comment: @JoshuaJeanThree: you did not share the whole code. You should give the full source code of your `main.cpp` to perhaps get more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freeing memory that you didn't allocate. The first such example is `residentData`.

You assign it in main to be `argv[1]` and latter call `delete[]` on it, although you did not allocate it. (Technically, you did allocate it. you just replaced it with `argv[1]` later).

As suggested by @Basile Starynkevitch, you probably want to run your code under valgrind. It'll pinpoint many memory errors.

Comment: When i remove delete[] residentData and others, the problem is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the error at compile time, but at run time.

I suggest compiling with `g++ -Wall -g` (and improve your code till no warnings are obtained) then debugging the memory leaks with [valgrind](http://valrgrind.org/) and of course the usual `gdb` debugger.